# Norm of Outer Product

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces, numerical-linear-algebra

Let $x \in \mathbb{R}^N$ and $ y\in \mathbb{R}^M$. Show that $\|xy^T\|_{\infty}=\|x\|_{\infty}\>\|y\|_1$

I've been able to show the following:

$\|xy^T\|_{\infty}= \|xIy^T\|_{\infty} \le \|xI\|_{\infty}\|y^T\|_{\infty} = \|x\|_{\infty}\|y^T\|_{\infty} \le \|x\|_{\infty}\|y^T\|_{1}$.

To complete the proof, I want to show $\|x\|_{\infty}\>\|y\|_1 \le\|xy^T\|_{\infty}$. I've attempted to do so with this:

$\|x\|_{\infty}\>\|y\|_1 = max_{1\le i \le N}\{x_i\}\|y\|_1 \le max_{1\le i \le N}\{x_i\}M\|y\|_{\infty} =M max_{1\le k\le M,1\le l\le N}\{(xy^T)_{kl}\} \le \|xy^T\|_{\infty.} $

I'm pretty sure that $M max_{1\le l\le M,1\le l\le N}\{(xy^T)_{lk}\} \le \|xy^T\|_{\infty.} $ is not a true statement, but I'm not sure why. Are there any other approaches to proving this?

Comment: What difficulty are you having with this exercise?

Comment: I have shown that the left hand side is less than or equal to the right hand side. I can't seem to figure out how to show the right hand side is less than or equal to the left hand side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matrix $\infty$-norm is simply the maximum of $1$-norms of the rows and the $i$th row of $xy^T$ is $x_iy^T$. So
$$
\|xy^T\|_{\infty}=\max_i \|x_iy^T\|_1=\max_i|x_i|\|y\|_1=\|x\|_{\infty}\|y\|_1.
$$

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer is not clear for me, so there goes mine:

Let $A=xy^T$, so $A \in \mathbb{R}^{N\times M}$, then

$$\|A\|_\infty=\max_{1 \le i \le N} \sum_{j=1}^M |a_{ij}|= \max_{1 \le i \le N} \sum_{j=1}^M |x_iy_j|=\max_{1 \le i \le N} |x_i| \sum_{j=1}^M |y_j|=\|x\|_\infty \|y\|_1$$